# C# Update Second Window from first

Tags: c#, wpf, window

how can i update a second Window (It's a simple WPF Window with a Progressbar to show a progress) from within my MainWindow inside a loop?

Well, i am loading a couple of Files which can cost about 10 Seconds. While loading i want my ProgressWindow to show how many Files have been loaded.

Here is my MainThread:

```
private void loadFiles(String[] paths) {

        // Show Progress Window
        MyProgressWindow progWindow = new MyProgressWindow();
        progWindow.ShowProgressWindow(0, paths.Length);
        //Globals.MyProgressController.ShowProgressWindow(0, paths.Length);

        foreach (String path in paths) {

            // Load the file
            loadFile(path);

            // Refresh the Table
            refreshTableAsync();

            // Update Progress Window
            progWindow.UpdateProgressWindow(1);
            //Globals.MyProgressController.UpdateProgressWindow(1);
        }

        // Close Progress Window
        progWindow.CloseProgressWindow();
        //Globals.MyProgressController.CloseProgressWindow();
    }
```

Here is the ProgressWindowController

```
public class MyProgressWindow {
    private ProgressWindow progressWindow;

    public void ShowProgressWindow(int startIndex, int maxIndex) {
        progressWindow = new ProgressWindow();
        progressWindow.Initialize(startIndex, maxIndex);
        progressWindow.Show();
    }

    public void UpdateProgressWindow(int value) {
        progressWindow.Update(value);
        //progressWindow.Update();
    }

    public void CloseProgressWindow() {
        progressWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

And finally the ProgressWindow itself:

```
public partial class ProgressWindow : Window {

    private int actualValue = 0;
    private int maxValue = 0;

    public ProgressWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Initialize(int startValue, int maxValue) {
        this.actualValue = startValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public void Update(int value) {
        actualValue += value;
        lblPercentage.Content = actualValue + " / " + maxValue;
        pbProgress.Value = ((double)value / maxValue) * 100;
    }
}
```

I have read thati should do it via threading, but i cannot get it to work, and all code I've found which helped other people, doesn't do what i need.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you could use the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern. you have one common ViewModel. The Mainwindow is updating and the SubWindow is just showing the data.

Comment: also you can add an event in a common area

Comment: Well i thought i could do it without the MVVM pattern, because it is just a little code snippet and bringing in some more complexity is not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is posed incorrectly. You are updating the second window as per your question, however the suggested advice of using a separate thread is what you're really asking about.

I suggest reading about the `BackgroundWorker` class [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) which even explains progress updates.